# Forward declare a type - what is the reason behind this

Tags: c

```
/* Forward declare a type "point" to be a struct. */
typedef struct point point;
/* Declare the struct with integer members x, y */
struct point {
   int    x;
   int    y;
};
```

can you explain the reason behind forward declaring ?

Comment: This is not a forward declaration, but a typedef.

Comment: but how is it different from typedef struct point{ }

Comment: During compilation, the c compiler only knows stuff that it has already read in.  The `typedef struct point point` tells the compiler that there is a type named `point` (which is enough).

Comment: @Theolodis, in fact it is both. The use of `struct point` inside the `typedef` is a forward declaration of the `struct` type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I notice that no one has actually answered the question you asked, which was

> What is the reason for forward-declaring a type?

The answer is: C was designed so that it could be compiled *by reading each file **once** going from top to bottom*.  Consider a language like C#:

```
class C
{
  B b;
}
class B
{
  C c;
}
```

Notice that if the compiler is going from top to bottom, the compiler gets to a field of type `B` before it knows what `B` is. And in fact the C# compiler does *not* read the entire file **once** going from top to bottom. It makes *many* passes over each file, building up information as it goes.

Now suppose you wanted to write a C# compiler that could parse the program above *without* doing multiple passes. Somehow you'd have to tell the compiler *before it encountered field `b`* that there was a type called `B`. But we can't just move `class B` to before `class C` because that would create the same problem again, this time with `C`!

In our imaginary one-pass version of C# you might say that you can get around the problem like this:

```
class B; // Tell the compiler that B will be defined later.
class C
{
  B b;
}
class B
{
  C c;
}
```

And there you go. When the compiler gets to `B b` it knows that `B` is a class that will be defined later. `B` has been *forward-declared*.

Since C# has always used a multi-pass approach it does not need this trick. But the designers of C *did* want a single-pass approach, and so they require the redundancy of a forward declare.

This single-pass approach was designed to make compilation easier back in the day when machines had a few K of memory and ran at a few thousand cycles per second; C#'s approach of multiple scans building up complex data structures each time is expensive in comparison, and would be difficult on a machine with constrained speed and memory.

Now of course we have machines with trillions of bytes of memory (remember, *memory* is *disk space*; RAM is just a cache over disk!) that run billions of cycles per second, and yet still we are stuck with having to use techniques to make compiler writer's lives easier back in the 1970s.  That's how it goes when you use C.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct point point;
struct point {
   int    x;
   int    y;
   point *next; /* Could be used */
};
```

vs

```
// typedef struct point point;
struct point {
   int    x;
   int    y;
   point *next; /* error: unknown type name ‘point’ */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What is typedef?

> The
>   purpose of typedef is to form complex types from more-basic machine
>   types and assign simpler names to such combinations. They are most
>   often used when a standard declaration is cumbersome, potentially
>   confusing, or likely to vary from one implementation to another.

So `typedef struct point point;` is not a forward declaration which you assume. It *names* `struct point` to be `point`, so that whenever you write `point` later, it will refer to `struct point`.

So now, you can declare a variable as `point p;` rather than `struct point p;`.

Comment: Not entirely correct as an answer. It is both. The use of `struct point` inside the `typedef` is a forward declaration of the `struct` type

Answer (score 1):

This is not a forward declaration of a `point`, this is a `typedef` for it <sup>*</sup>. The `typedef` lets you write

```
point p;
```

instead of

```
struct point p;
```

The forward declaration effect is not used in your code. However, with the `typedef` in place you could start using `point` as a type name, rather than a `struct` tag, inside the declaration of the `point` structure.

A more common way of achieving the same effect is to combine the definition and the `typedef`, like this:

```
typedef struct point {
   int    x;
   int    y;
} point;
```

<sup>*</sup> The `typedef` happens to forward-declare the type, but that is a "side effect".

Comment: Not entirely correct as an answer. It is both. The use of struct point inside the typedef is a forward declaration of the struct type

Comment: @JensGustedt This is precisely what I say in the footnote.

Comment: What do you mean by "side effect"? It is important that this is a forward declaration, you can only declare `typedef`s of known types. And from then on `point*` works perfectly even without knowing the `struct`.

Comment: @JensGustedt By "side effect" I mean "it happens, too". If someone whats to forward-declare a `struct` tag, he writes `struct point;` and starts using `struct point *` without knowing the specifics of the `struct`. That is what happens when he wants the "direct" effect. When someone writes a `typedef`, he wants it primarily for the `typedef`, i.e. for the ability to drop `struct` when using `struct point`. The fact that after the `typedef` compiler considers the type declared, and lets you use `struct point *`, is "secondary" behavior.