# What are "prototypes" in a C program?

Tags: c, prototype

The book's I'm using to learn C explains something called "prototypes" which I couldn't understand properly. In the book, the following sample code explains these "prototypes". What does this mean here? What are the "prototypes"?

```
//* two_func.c -- a program using two functions in one file */
#include <stdio.h>
void butler(void);
int main(void)
{
    printf("I will summon the butler function.\n");
    butler();
    printf("Yes! bring me some tea and writable DVD's.\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void butler(void)   /*start of function definition*/

{
    printf("You rang,sir.\n");

}
```

Please explain in simple terms.

Comment: defined in your header files, declarations of functions.  in your example you have no header file so you simply declared the `butler()` in the source.

Comment: What does the book say about this?

Comment: comment out your prototype and then try to run your code

Comment: In the future, it's usually helpful to answerers if you describe the things you _do_ understand, however little and confused that might be.

Comment: @stefan The C90 standard added prototypes, and older compilers might not recognize them. (We’ll tell
you what to do when using such compilers in a moment.) A prototype declares to the compiler
that you are using a particular function, so it’s called a function declaration . It also specifies
properties of the function. For example, the first void in the prototype for the butler() function
indicates that butler() does not have a return value. (In general, a function can return
a value to the calling function for its use, but butler() doesn’t.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned in the "close as a duplicate note" (i.e. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568612/forward-declare-a-type-what-is-the-reason-behind-this)): the questions talk about different kinds of prototypes - this one asks about prototypes for functions, while the other ones asks about prototypes for data types. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Before now I've never even considered that one might consider two things to be *different*. How are they different?

Comment: @EricLippert Although both kinds of prototypes serve the same purpose as far as the compiler is concerned, they differ to someone who is starting to learn the language. While a function prototype lets you call the function without restrictions, a prototype of a data type only lets you declare pointers to that data type; one can neither reference fields of the prototype-only data type nor declare variables or non-pointer parameters of that type. Back in my teaching days, I used to introduce them in two different units.

Answer (score 10):

Function *prototypes* (also called "forward declarations") declare functions without providing the "body" right away. You write prototypes in addition to the functions themselves in order to tell the compiler about the function that you define elsewhere:

Your prototype `void butler(void);` does all of the following things:

- It tells the compiler that function `butler` exists,
- It tells that `butler` takes no parameters, and
- It tells that `butler` does not return anything.

Prototypes are useful because they help you hide implementation details of the function. You put your prototypes in a header file of your library, and place the implementation in a C file. This lets the code that depends on your library to be compiled separately from your code - a very important thing.

Comment: what do you mean by "no arguments" and "not return antyhing" ??

Comment: @user3205705 I mean function parameters, the data that you can pass into the function.

Comment: One more thing, line 3 -- void butler(void); --  uses parentheses while line 13 -- void butler(void) --  don't uses it? what difference are the parentheses actually making?

Comment: Generally it is like a "warm-up" for the compiler.Compiler is clever enough to compile the file and run fine,in most circumstances,even if you do not provide him prototypes of functions!It is a good practice to declare prototypes in order to help your compiler!

Comment: @user3205705 I assume that by "parentheses" you mean curly braces (i.e. `{` and `}`) not the regular "round" parentheses present on both lines. It is the absence of the curly braces that makes the prototype a *prototype*, rather than a full-blown function definition. If you put curly braces after a prototype instead of a semicolon `;`, you end up with a function *definition* that happens to have an empty body. Such "do nothing" functions are perfectly fine - C allows them, and they are also useful when you want to compile and run some partially implemented code.

Comment: @user3205705 You are welcome! If you are satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it to let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution. This would earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In this context *prototype* is a more generic term for what in C would be called a function declaration, i.e.:

```
void butler(void);
```

You may also find it called *function signature*. Both terms actually refer more to how `butler()` is defined from a conceptual point of view, as a function that doesn't take any argument and doesn't return a value, rather that to the fact that its declaration is enough for you to use it in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the prototype:

```
void butler(void);
```

Basically it defines `butler` as a function that takes no parameters and has no return value. It allows the compiler to continue onwards, even though the `butler` function has not yet really been defined. Note that the prototype doesn't contain any actual code. It simply defines what the butler function looks like from the outside. The actual code can come later in the file.

If your code had been

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    butler(); // note this line
}

void butler() { return; }
```

The compiler would have stopped at the `note this line` section, complaining that `butler()` doesn't exist. It will not scan the whole file first for functions, it'll simply stop at the first undefined function call it encounters.

Comment: Actually, it may just issue a warning about implicit declaration and move on. An implicit function declaration is not a compilation error (though I agree it should be; no one should be relying on implicit declarations these days)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves the diagnostic is required and a program that requires a diagnostic is not a strictly conforming program. Moreover an implementation may refuse to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype comprises the return type of a function, its name and the order of different types of parameters that you pass it.
If you write the function definition before calling the function, then a prototype is not necessary. But, as is the case in your example, the function `butler()` is called BEFORE its definition and so, a prototype is necessary to tell the compiler that such a function exists which will have so and so return type and parameters.
Otherwise, writing the function definition after calling the function will result in error.

Comment: One more thing, line 3 -- void butler(void); --  uses parentheses while line 13 -- void butler(void) --  don't uses it? what difference are the parentheses actually making?

Comment: Oh no parenthesis differentiate a variable from a function, and you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
void butler(void);
```

Is Called prototype or declaration of function.

And below is the function definition.

```
void butler(void)   /*function definition */

{
    printf("You rang,sir.\n");

}
```