# What is the purpose of defining such a function?

Tags: c, function

```
int func (int,int);

int main ()
{ 
     printf("hello");
}
```

Consider the above function. What is the purpose of defining functions like `func`? I have seen this repeatedly.

Comment: That's not a function definition, but a **function prototype**. Prototypes reports the minimal info's to allow compiler to use the function that can be defined elsewhere (i.e. in an object library). Knowing from prototype what a function returns and which parameters gets is enough to correctly link it to your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are "prototypes" in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661729/what-are-prototypes-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 1):

```
int func(int, int);
```

does not *define* a function, but declares it by providing its prototype. It's the "promise" to the compiler, that latest the linker will provide a module exposing such a function.

The prototype for a function covers its:

- return type
- name
- the *type* and order of the arguments

The arguments' names are not relevant in the context of a declaration.

The function's arguments' names only need to be provided for the function's implementation, which might look like this:

```
int func(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

---

On the other hand this

```
int func(int a, int)
{
  return a;
}
```

is **not valid**.

The C Standard clearly states:

> [**6.9.1/5 Function definitions**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p5)
>
> If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the declaration of each parameter shall
>   include an identifier, except for the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single
>   parameter of type void, in which case there shall not be an identifier. No declaration list
>   shall follow.

Comment: Have you tried to compile this "not valid" code? it looks valid. Not providing the name of the parameter in the implementation is a technique used to suppress the "unused parameter" warning

Comment: @RSFalcon7: I'd expect  trying to compile `int func(int a, int)
{
  return a;
}` to result in an error like this: `error: parameter name omitted` in C at least, unsure about C++.

Comment: @RSFalcon7: "*used to suppress the "unused parameter" warning*" I'd consider this a vendor specific extension to the C Standard. Please prove me wrong by citing the relevant parts of C Standard.

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Please see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8776810/694576 There seems to be one more  slight difference between C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are not answering the correct question explicitly, so I'm adding one here.

First of all, it's not a function **definition** because the body is missing. This semantic is called **function declaration**.

Before calling a function, the compiler needs to know what exactly the function is. This is named a "prototype". A prototype must be known before generating correct code to call a function. Consider this code:

```
// No previous info
int a = func(1, 3);
```

The compiler doesn't know if it is calling `int func(int, int)` or `long func(char, double)`, nor can it perform error checking if the actual function is `FILE* func(void*)`.

With a correct  prototype privided, the compiler is able to perform necessary checking and generate the corresponding code of that function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is not function defination but it is a functions declaration. A function declaration informs the compiler of the number of parameters the function has, the type of the function parameters and the type of the function return value.

> 1) It tells the return type of the data that the function will return.
>
> 2) It tells the number of arguments passed to the function.
>
> 3) It tells the data types of the each of the passed arguments.
>
> 4) Also it tells the order in which the arguments are passed to the
>   function.
>
> 5) It tells the name (identifier) of the function.

Comment: 5) It tells the name (identifier) of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a **function declaration** of a function to tell compiler that a function with name `func` exists having definition at end.
Consider this example:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    int func (int,int);
    int main()
    {
         printf("hello\n");
         int c= func(5,4);
         printf("%d\n",c);

    }
    int func(int a, int b)
    {

         return a+b;
    }
```

Comment: `return` isn't a function. There is no need to warp its argument into parenthesis.

Comment: Formally it's not wrong, not wrong as `return ((a) + (b));` would not be wrong.